# Laravel: How to register user through login?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, registration

I am using the standard method of `login/registration` of Auth Controllers. The goal is to register a new user when the user logs in if there is no such user, or just auth if there is. To my mind, it should be simply reassigning a couple of methods. For start, I changed

```
AuthenticatesUsers.php

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }


        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        //return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

With commenting the last line it will not say that there is no such user, and I believe right there I should put register method, but I can't find the right way to include it. I suggest that I should use `RegisterUsers.php`
```

AuthenticatesUsers.php is the controller that does login logic. We are looking at the public function login

```
    AuthenticatesUsers.php
    <?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins, RegistersUsers;


    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);


        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }


        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        //return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        $this->register($request);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            //'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            //'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }

    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

Comment: So when a user misspells his email/username, the user will log-in to a new account with the misspelled email/username?
In case an email/username is not unique, will he even create a new account if the user misspells the password?

Comment: Yes, if he misstypes he will be registered as a new user, please don't ask me why I need this. The email must be unique

Comment: I do not ask why you need it, I just hereby warn you, that your users will hate it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

simply override the `register` method from `RegisterUsers.php` into your `LoginController`.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Also add the `validator` protected function from `RegisterController` and edit according to your fields.

Also keep in mind to edit the `User` model `fillable` array and the relatively migration file of creating `users` table. Set `Nullable()` to fields you are not going to enter during `Login`.

Comment: tried something like this but keep getting errors, like Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make()

Comment: add this in your controller `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Registered' not found....when I add the class after clicking submit it writes that the page has expired

Comment: also add this in your Controller `use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;` , `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;` and put this ` use RegistersUsers;` inside the `class`.

Comment: I tried this also and got 'Trait method redirectPath has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers' this is crazy

Comment: heres the setting: namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins, RegistersUsers;

Comment: can you post your whole controller?

Comment: I posted it in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170524/discussion-between-dima-rashevskiy-and-parthu-panther).

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method in your LoginController

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    // here you can check if user is present or just create.
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this. If I put this it will do the thing?

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::attemptLogin() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 44

Comment: This is a method to log in a user, and I want to create a user

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is to turn to User model, no need to specify any methods
here is how the function in `AuthenticatesUsers.php` should look like:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    //return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    $user = User::where('email', '=', $_POST['email'])->first();
    if ($user === null) {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $_POST['email'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($_POST['password']),
        ]);
    }
    else
        echo 'Wrong password';
}
```